# Tool to save data on Linux, like TripMode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring

I'm looking for a tool for Linux like [TripMode](https://tripmode.ch/) that is designed to help the user minimize Internet usage (in order to "save data"), and optionally monitor Internet usage of apps.

Ideally, I'm looking for something with an easy to use GUI. I don't particularly want to set up complicated firewall settings on the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [Gufw](https://gufw.org/).

I have to admit that I haven't tried [TripMode](https://tripmode.ch/) or [Gufw](https://gufw.org/) myself.

If you are looking for something firewall-like on Android, I can definitely recommend [NetGuard](https://netguard.me/)